# Postgres 13 started giving error to python data ingestion after upgrade from 9.6

Tags: python, postgresql, databricks, metadata, tableau-api

we have upgraded tableau and postgres. Postgres is upgraded from 9.6 to 13. We have one python ingestion system which runs over Databricks as a job. It connects to postgres and ingests data. Now, it is giving the error below:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported.
Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP
address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
```

There is no change in passwords and users. Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with databricks, but I guess it is not related the password itself, but to the password encryption. What are you using? `md5` ?

Comment: I got pass,username,servername & port from team and used simple python utility to ingest data. I am not using md5

Comment: Is the `pg_hba.conf` also configured to work with plaintext passwords?

Comment: What Jim means, can you share your pg_hba.conf entry corresponding to the your databricks client? pg_hba.conf file is located in your database server, more specifically, in the data directory. Masking the IP address would be better.

Comment: I am not allowed to update anything on database server. Is there anything we can do with python utility alone.

Comment: The issue is that `scram-sha-256` password authentication was introduced in Postgres 10. Best bet is that the Python driver(`psycopg2`) you are using has not been updated to one that can deal with the new authentication, which is why you are getting; *The authentication type 10 is not supported.*

Comment: That should have been `Python driver(psycopg2?)`.  At any rate something in your Python database stack has not been updated to a version that recognizes `authentication type 10(scram-sha-256)`.